# AWS-SDK-RUBY stub a call to get_object

Tags: aws-sdk-ruby

How do you stub a call to get_object using a client & encrypted client?  Goal is to write rspec tests to get_object using the following clients. Does anyone have a "get_object" working example they can share? I am aware of various web pages that describe aws-sdk-ruby stubs but haven't been able to get anything working.

```
Aws::S3::Client.new
Aws::S3::Encryption::Client.new
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/tag/testing/) you can use

```
# stub everything
Aws.config[:stub_responses] = true
```

which is supposed to prevent all http call.